# Installed OS version not matching /proc/version

Tags: operating-system, version, centos7, proc

I installed Centos v7.2 While I do cat /proc/version I see this

```
Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015
```

Why is this Red Hat 4.8.3-9? Should it not be in versions of 7.x.x?

Comment: Also if I can get to all the fields and columns of the output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/version` specifies the version of the installed kernel ("3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64" in your case) and the version of gcc used to compile it ( "4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)").

The CentOS/RHEL version can be found in `/etc/redhat-release`.